# How do I use apk in a docker image built from busybox:1.31.1-glibc

Tags: docker

I am running a container built with `FROM busybox:1.31.1-glibc` as the base image, but now when I am in the container and I try to use `apk` to install packages it does not work. For example:

```
/ # apk add curl
/bin/sh: apk: not found
```

How do I go about adding packages to this running container if I want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The busybox image doesn't have a package manager. It's intended for final distribution of build artifacts like a binary, with a few shell utilities for convenience. Typical usage would be as as the final base image in a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

`apk` is the Alpine package manager. If you want to use it, you'll need to use [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) as your base image in your Dockerfile.

Comment: I see. I think I might be in a fix. I need to run a binary that requires some dynamic lib to be present. This is what I was thinking of installing...but it seems I have to find another way around this